# Do banks/companies or investors give personal loans for X years?

Tags: personal-loan

I was wondering is it possible that I could get a loan somehow and pay it back in full in 5-10 years instead of monthly payments? It seems like a long shot but no harm in asking..

I understand there are 30+ year mortgages on homes, is there something similar for personal loans? would a bank/investor give me a line of credit based on future assets? Could I use a copy of a Will as future collateral or something?

My elderly mother is rich and me and my brother are the only benefactors from her Will and she has life insurance, real estate property, etc. so there would be no problem paying the loan back even if it had a high interest rate.

I'm not looking to borrow anything too crazy (I think $50k or $100k would last 5/10 years at $1000 per month for living expenses)

UPDATE: I tried to ask my mother but she is very old school and thinks I should earn everything, even though she never had a job herself.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/128410/discussion-on-question-by-richmompoorson-do-banks-companies-or-investors-give-pe). (And note, once again, comments have gotten a bit unkind) Further comments will be removed with no notice.

Answer (score 2):

The key to getting a low interest rate loan is to have collateral. That is usually a car, or a house. The other way to get a somewhat low interest loan is to have somebody guarantee it. This could be in the form of a cosigner who has collateral, or when you get a student loan backed by the Federal government.

Unfortunately a copy of the will, or a copy of the insurance company will not count as collateral. Somebody besides you can change the terms of those documents and you would not be getting as much as you expect. That could mean the the lender will not have anything backing the loan.

If you had equity in a house that you own, it is possible to get a 2nd mortgage via a line of credit. A line of credit could be a lump sum or you could draw from it when you need it. You would have to check with possible lenders regarding terms during the period where you had the ability to pull funds, followed by the payback period. It is possible that somebody has this type of line of credit.

Most loans are structured to have you pay at least the interest in the early years, otherwise the accumulating interest can make it riskier for the lender, and more expensive for the borrower.

Comment: That depends on the lender.  While I have no personal experience (lacking rich relatives), fiction - particularly British mysteries from the interwar period - is full of instances of people borrowing against their expectations, so presumably it can be done.  Of course there are numerous catches, such as the rich relative not dying on schedule (a common plot driver) or changing the will...